# How can i create a file like test.xml with the ant code

Tags: ant

i want to create a test.xml file through the command of ant tasks.

Comment: <echo file="test.xml" message="this is creation of xml file"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this site containing code for what you want....

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/r_cc_rtc_ext_samp.html

Answer (score 3):

try this one

< touch file="test.xml" >